# is there any way to implement clickhouse condition view

Tags: database, view, conditional-statements, clickhouse

i'd like to find a way to implement a **clickhouse** (view|table) which can handling where conditions like

```
select * from sometable where a=1 and b=2 and c='whatever' and e=4+1
```

can returns

```
+-+-+--------+-+
|a|b|c       |d|
+-+-+--------+-+
|1|2|whatever|5|
+-+-+--------+-+
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  ClickHouse SQL syntax handles simple WHERE clauses like like, just as any other SQL database.

Comment: sorry my bad, 
i mean im looking for a  dynamic table or view function (not a real table) from clickhouse.
if i set  the condition where `hello=1`, the table will return my condition with a column names 'hello' and the value is what in the where condition = 1.   
i think that will easily to make a UDTF.